# Serving static content with JAX-RS

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

I am using Jersey's JAX-RS implementation and I'd like to serve static content like html, css and images. Is there something already done that I could use or I have to manually load the file and deal with the http headers. If no, is there any good jax-rs tutorials for serving static content ? Please, note that I'm not that much interested in the configuration file rather than what should really happen inside the method.

Comment: I wonder you want to use web service for static contents

Comment: You are probably using Jersey in a web container. Why not just using the web container for discovering static resources?

Comment: You could also read the static resource to a stream an return it.

Comment: I need to apply some filters before returining the stream, that's why I wanted to transform the static servlet into jax-rs serivce.

Comment: Can these filters be implemented as normal Servlet filters?